# Extract all the unique values for a given substring in the column names

Tags: r, apply, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe where the colunm names have a structure as follows:

```
Barcelona.Standard.2012.True
Berlin.One.2013.True
London.One.2014.True
Barcelona.Standard.2015.True
Berlin.One.2016.True
```

As you can see, each columns specifies the `City`, `Type of bank account`, `Year it was open` and if it's `Active` or not.

I want to extract into a list, all the different possibilities for each of the categories. For example, for the first category, which is the city, we would get:

`Barcelona` `Berlin` `London`

What I though of doing is splitting by the symbol `.` and then getting all the unique values for a given position for all the columns.

I could do this with a loop, but I would like to do it with a sapply, if that's possible.

Something like:

```
lapply(strsplit(colnames(dat), split = "\\.")[[]][1])
```

Where  `[[]]` would be all the columns.

This is just a toy example, the real dataset has thousands of columns.

Comment: I don't think there's a need to loop or use `<x>apply` at all.  Does `stringr::str_split(colnames(dat), stringr::fixed("."))` give you what you need?  [Is the `|` in item 3 a typo?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sapply`:

```r
sapply(transpose(strsplit(col, "\\.")), function(x) unlist(unique(x), recursive = F))
```

Or use `data.table::transpose` instead of transpose to make it easier:

```r
sapply(data.table::transpose(strsplit(col, "\\.")), unique)
```

Finally, use `setNames` to set the names:

```r
sapply(transpose(strsplit(col, "\\.")), function(x) unlist(unique(x), recursive = F)) |>
  setNames(c("City", "Type", "Year", "Active"))
```

**output**:

```r
$City
[1] "Barcelona" "Berlin"    "London"   

$Type
[1] "Standard" "One"     

$Year
[1] "2012" "2013" "2014" "2015" "2016"

$Active
[1] "True"
```

**data**

```r
col <- c("Barcelona.Standard.2012.True",
  "Berlin.One.2013.True",
  "London.One.2014.True",
  "Barcelona.Standard.2015.True",
  "Berlin.One.2016.True")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `tidyr::separate` and the new base R >= 4.1 pipe operator and lambda.

```r
tidyr::separate(
  dat, x, 
  into = c("City", "Type", "Year", "Active"),
  sep = "[^[:alnum:]]"
) |>
  as.list() |>
  (\(x) Map(unique, x))()
#> $City
#> [1] "Barcelona" "Berlin"    "London"   
#> 
#> $Type
#> [1] "Standard" "One"     
#> 
#> $Year
#> [1] "2012" "2013" "2014" "2015" "2016"
#> 
#> $Active
#> [1] "True"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

Simpler, with `lapply` instead of `Map`.

```r
tidyr::separate(
  dat, x, 
  into = c("City", "Type", "Year", "Active"),
  sep = "[^[:alnum:]]"
) |>
  (\(x) lapply(x, unique))()
#> $City
#> [1] "Barcelona" "Berlin"    "London"   
#> 
#> $Type
#> [1] "Standard" "One"     
#> 
#> $Year
#> [1] "2012" "2013" "2014" "2015" "2016"
#> 
#> $Active
#> [1] "True"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Data

```r
x <- scan(text = "
Barcelona.Standard.2012.True
Berlin.One.2013.True
London.One|2014.True
Barcelona.Standard.2015.True
Berlin.One.2016.True", what = character())

dat <- data.frame(x)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>